# How to show small image in its original size?

Tags: tailwind-css

On site with tailwindcss 3.1 I define class

```
.view_image {
    @apply border-2 border-gray-300 p-1 rounded-lg w-64;
    height: auto;
 }
```

and it is looking good for most of images, but if image is small (less then w-64)
the image looks ugly.
If there is a way for this image if it is less then w-64 to show it in its original size ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `w-64` into `max-w-[16rem]` - it is `max-width` property. This way images will stretch to its original size, but if their width more than 16rem, it will stop stretching and has width of 16rem. Tailwind has not this value for Tailwind, as you can see [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width), so either use arbitrary value `max-w-[16rem]` or extend configuration file

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Qo3lUManCY)